# "All Files Permission" setting option GREYED OUT (Android)

Tags: android, scoped-storage

My App requires access to some special file extensions and it's using a built-in file browser.
Before displaying the file browser the App asks for permissions, depending on the OS version.

Right now, it is working fine on Android 10 and below, but on Android 11+ the All Files Permission option is greyed out.

```
<manifest
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="***.***.***"
requestLegacyExternalStorage="true">

<uses-permission 
    android:maxSdkVersion="29"
    android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission 
    android:maxSdkVersion="29"
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission-sdk-30
    android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

```
try {
                intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION);
                intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT");
                intent.setData(Uri.parse(String.format("package:%s",getApplicationContext().getPackageName())));
                startActivityForResult(intent, PERMISSION_REQUEST_EXT_STORAGE);
            } 
            catch (Exception e) {
                intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION);
                startActivityForResult(intent, PERMISSION_REQUEST_EXT_STORAGE );
            }
            break;
```

[image]

My code seems to be working but something is missing, as you can see in the picture below the setting option is greyed out on my testing device and for all my users.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do without addCategory().

Comment: `<uses-permission-sdk-30` Try with just `<uses-permission`.

Comment: any update on this as I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: The solution in my case was to add this line to **AndroidManifest.xml**:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE">`

Comment: Having the same issue any solution u found ??